# How to create a responsive grid with slide down panel similar to iTunes album view

Tags: css, tabs

I would like to recreate the iTunes album view effect on the web and it must be responsive. I made an animated GIF to show the desired effect: http://files.katart.com/sgDkRGI

I've started a codepen using flexbox, but I can't seem to get the tabs to stay at the top. You can view it here: https://codepen.io/katartgraphics/pen/pWvNrP

Here is the markup:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
    $('.tab').on('click', function() {
        $(this).siblings('.tab-content').slideUp();
        $(this).next().slideDown();
    });
});
```

```css
.tabs-wrapper {
    margin: 48px auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.tab-container {
    max-width: 960px;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0 24px;
}

.tab > span {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 42px;
    max-width: 280px;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0 20px;
    color: #555;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 600;
    line-height: 42px;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    border-bottom: none;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.tab-content {
    display: none;
    padding-top: 1rem;
    padding-bottom: 1rem;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: tomato;
}

.tab-content > *:first-child { margin-top: 0; }
.tab-content > *:last-child { margin-bottom: 0; }

@media (min-width: 600px) {
    .tabs-wrapper {
        position: relative;
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: row wrap;
        justify-content: center;
    }
    
    .tab {
        positiion: relative;
        top: 0;
        flex: 0 1 auto;
    }
    
    .tab-content {
        position: relative;
        top: 0;
        flex: 1 1 100%;
    }
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tabs-wrapper">
    
    <div class="tab"><span>Tab 1</span></div>
    <div id="tab1" class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-container">
            <h4>Tab 1 Content</h4>
            <p>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Integer posuere erat a ante venenatis dapibus posuere velit aliquet. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="tab"><span>Tab 2</span></div>
    <div id="tab2" class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-container">
            <h4>Tab 2 Content</h4>
            <p>Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="tab"><span>Tab 3</span></div>
    <div id="tab3" class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-container">
            <h4>Tab 3 Content</h4>
            <p>Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="tab"><span>Tab 4</span></div>
    <div id="tab4" class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-container">
            <h4>Tab 4 Content</h4>
            <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<h2>Other Content</h2>
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quis sapiente quod unde, dicta asperiores ipsa nam eius earum quisquam natus tempore molestias necessitatibus consequuntur id ab illum modi assumenda reprehenderit!</div>
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed eligendi commodi facilis qui aut totam ipsam neque quod tempore omnis corrupti quaerat tenetur labore nesciunt, eum pariatur molestias velit a!</div>
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium sequi unde iure iste aperiam ipsum officia temporibus consequuntur a pariatur aliquid, autem error, velit nam ad vitae eius deleniti cum.</div>
```